# Jupyter notebook and matplotlib (runtime warning): continue to display plots after closing

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I would like to use matplotlib.pyplot to display many images in my jupyter notebook. However, when I try to display more than 20, a runtime warning appears, since images are kept in memory if not closed:

> RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control this warning, see the rcParam figure.max_open_warning).

I am using `%matplotlib inline`

If I close the plot `plt.close()`, the plots are not displayed. How can I can close the plot and still look at the plot in jupyter, I need to look at many images simultanously: I am using a loop where crop and value are two images.

```
plt.figure()
f, axarr = plt.subplots(1,2)
plt.title('Image: ' + str(key))
plt.gray()
axarr[0].imshow(crop)
axarr[1].imshow(value)
plt.close()
```

Comment: It's a _warning_, not something that actually stops things being displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you would want to use `plt.show()` at the end of your loop.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for i in range(25):
    fig, ax_arr = plt.subplots(1,2)
    ax_arr[0].imshow(np.random.randn(10,10))
    ax_arr[1].imshow(np.random.randn(10,10))
    plt.show()
```

There is then no need to close anything.